# Metadata fetch failed stack driver logging Google Compute Engine

Tags: docker-compose, metadata, google-cloud-platform

I am integrating my go application with Stackdriver logging via `cloud.google.com/go/logging`. My application works perfectly fine when deployed in a GCP on Flex engine. However, when I run my app in local, as soon as I hit `localhost:8080` I get the following error on my console and the application gets killed automatically:

```
Metadata fetch failed: Get http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/gae_project: dial tcp: lookup metadata on 127.0.0.
11:53: server misbehaving
```

My understanding is that when running locally, the code should not try to access Google's internal metadata, which is what is happening above. I dug deeper and looks like this part is handled in the code `cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata/metadata.go`. I might be wrong here but it looks like I have to set an env variable for the code to work properly. Pasting from the documentation in `metadata.go`

```
// metadataHostEnv is the environment variable specifying the
    // GCE metadata hostname.  If empty, the default value of
    // metadataIP ("169.254.169.254") is used instead.
    // This is variable name is not defined by any spec, as far as
    // I know; it was made up for the Go package.
    metadataHostEnv = "GCE_METADATA_HOST"
```

If all of my understanding is true, what should I set `GCE_METADATA_HOST` to? If I am wrong about my understanding, why am I seeing this error? Is it possible that this error has something to do with my Docker and not with Stackdriver logging?

I am running my app with in a container with docker-compose. I am performing `go install` which generates the binary and then I am simply executing the binary.

EDIT: This is my compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  dev:
    image: <gcr_image>
    entrypoint:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - "cat ./config-scripts/config.sh >> /root/.bashrc; bash"
    command: bash
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    working_dir: /code
    environment:
    - ENV1=value1
    - ENV2=value2
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
    - .:/code
    - ~/.npmrc:/root/.npmrc
    - ~/.config/gcloud:/root/.config/gcloud
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: How are you running the container? Since you have mentioned `docker-compose` please post the compose file

Comment: @TarunLalwani I am spinning my container with `docker-compose up`. Added the compose file

Comment: Try two things. Add a environment `GCE_METADATA_HOST=169.254.169.254`, if that doesn't work then remove it and add `extract_hosts:<nextline>- "metadata:169.254.169.254"`

Comment: I don't need to add the env because 169.254.169.254 is used by default. The code https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/blob/master/compute/metadata/metadata.go has good documentation.

I still went ahead and tried it but didn't help

Comment: What about the extra_hosts approach?

Comment: What is the extra_hosts approach? Did not find it in the documentation.

Comment: add `extract_hosts:<nextline>- "metadata:169.254.169.254"` to your service in compose file. The `<nextline>` i mentioned is a new line character, as I can't format code in comments

Comment: Tried that, getting connection refused (I did perform `gcloud auth login` before launching my app)
`2017/10/04 14:52:35 Metadata fetch failed: Get http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/gae_project: dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: getsockopt: connection refused`

Comment: From the looks at the documentation it should be `metadata.google.internal`. Can you try adding `google.internal` as `dns_search` in the compose file

Comment: From the docs, any of the following 3 should work 

1. Full URL: http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1
2. Shorthand URL: http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/
3. IP address: http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/


https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/KQPEdvB9SW4
https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/openstack/